# $http get fails

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

In my controller I've built GetUsersByJson Action:

```
public ActionResult GetUsersByJson()
    {
        DataLayer dal = new DataLayer();
        return Json(dal.Users.ToList<User>(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

`dal.Users.ToList<User>()` retrieves users from my database, this method works well and the retrieved JSON is valid.

Then in a script I did:

```
$scope.load = function () {
                $http({ method: "GET", url: "GetUsersByJson" }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.users = data;
                });
            };
$scope.load();
```

but it doesn't go into the success function.

Comment: Shouldn't the URL be "/GetUsersByJson"? Besides that, your success parameters don't match the type returned by the method (I could be wrong, but this will hold true is plain jQuery)

Comment: I did the same thing in other pages, like ViewProducts and it works.
By the way, i've placed breakpoint in GetUsersByJson and it reached it, and the json is valid

Comment: Then add an error function, and it will most likely be reached with some kind of information

Comment: why not wire up the $http.error method and see if your code ends up there? Also, the success/error style of HTTPCallouts in angular has been deprecated. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I don't know that what they thaught us in class, any way I've tried .then like they showed there, and the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You had wrong `URL` in your `$http.get` call it should be `/MyController/GetUsersByJson` as default route is been already there in `RouteConfig.cs`.

Also you need to use `.then` instead of `.success`/`.error` method, since they are [**`$http` callbacks are deprecated**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice).

**Code**

```
$scope.load = function () {
    $http({ method: "GET", url: "/MyController/GetUsersByJson" })
    .then(function (response) {
         $scope.users = response.data;
     }, function(error){
         console.log(error); //this will print error in console.
     });
};
$scope.load();
```

Comment: Tried that also, same result.
And in other views I did the same thing as I did in the question, for example:
$http({ method: "GET", url: "GetProductsByJsonForView" }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.Products = data;
                    $scope.lock = false;
                });
and it worked.

Comment: what is you MVC controller name? and did you check developer console(by pressing F12) is there any error?

Comment: SignUpController.
And I placed debugger in the code, and followed it, but other than breakpoints I don't know much how to use it.. first time I'm web programming

Comment: @Erez try edited code..and then look at the console.. you will get an error in console.look into that error object

Answer (score 0):

Try using **.then** instead of **.success**
[See this.](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/)

Comment: explaining Why is a big part of learning and will help the asker from returning with similar problems in the future. It would also help to post where you would make the substitution for better readability for people referencing this question in the future. Helping the initial user is only the very first goal of any answer.

Comment: Try adding an error handler as well as second callback in .then. See if it gives some error.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.users = data;
            });
```

Try

```
.then(function (data) {
                $scope.users = data;
            });
```